# integers are being repeated?

Tags: c, sorting

I'm writing a program that reads integers from keyboard input and find the occurrence then sort them in descending order.
I got the occurrence and the descending but when I type same integers, they are repeated if I type 8 7 8
it's like
8 2
8 2
7 1
help please??
This is my code

```
#pragma warning (disable :4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    int input;
    int inputarr[50], count[50] = {0};
    int i=0, j;
    int last = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers \n");


    ///getting int
    while (scanf("%d", &input) > 0)
    {
        inputarr[i] = input;
        i++;
    }

        last = i;

        printf("  N       Count\n");
        printf("-----     -----\n");
        int a;

        /// increment count
        for (i = 0; i < last; i++){
            count[inputarr[i]] = count[inputarr[i]] + 1;
        }

        /////ascending
        for (i = 0; i < last; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < last; j++){
                if (inputarr[j]<inputarr[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = inputarr[j];
                    inputarr[j] = inputarr[j + 1];
                    inputarr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            printf(" %d           %d\n", inputarr[i], count[inputarr[i]]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After sorting, and displays by skipping `inputarr` with the same value.

Comment: look at inputarr when j=last-1 => inputarr[j+1]=inputarr[last], moreover I suppose that the inversion should be done (While inversions) because one loop only I think isn't sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this code is that you are printing the array while it's being sorted. Inputing numbers 1 2 3 4 would result in numbers 2 1 4 1 2 1 1 1 being outputed. To accomplish what you wanted you should move the printing part out of the sorting loop. Even then when a number is appearing multiple times in the input the output won't contain it only once (ex. 8 7 8 -> 8 2 8 2 7 2). To do that you should not output the number if it is the same as the previous number you outputed.

Another thing, in the sorting loop you are potentially  accessing non existing array elements at the line

```
for (j = 0; j < last; j++){
```

When j = last-1 you are accessing last element which might not exsist.

After fixing all this problems code might look like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < last; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < last-1; j++){
            if (inputarr[j]<inputarr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = inputarr[j];
                inputarr[j] = inputarr[j + 1];
                inputarr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    if (last == 0)
        return 0;
    printf(" %d           %d\n", inputarr[0], count[inputarr[0]]);
    for(i = 1; i < last; i++)
        if (inputarr[i] != inputarr[i-1])
            printf(" %d           %d\n", inputarr[i], count[inputarr[i]]);
```

Comment: ohhh Thanks! It worked perfectly!!
And can you explain the latter part more? like how it works? I'm not quite sure I get it :'(

Comment: Lets take a look at the array 1 4 4 6 4. When sorted, it looks like 6 4 4 4 1, and you want to print each number of that array only once. Notice that when there are multiple numbers in the array, when sorted they are all one after another. Lets call the first one in that group of the same numbers an original and every other an copy. Notice how behind every copy is the number equal to that copy, and behind every original a number different from that original. By excluding all the copies with `if (inputarr[i] != inputarr[i-1])` you only print the original.

Comment: @3348701 Also you need to print the first element separately because you can't check if the element before it is different (it is the first one hence the element before doesn't exist).
This part
`if (last == 0)
        return 0;`
is to prevent the first element being printed in case that there are no elements at all.